# Problems compiling code with libcurl in Netbeans in Windows/Cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, curl, netbeans, cygwin

I just started using C++ but I am having problems compiling a code in Windows/Cygwin which uses libcurl. I believe I correctly installed the library, but when I try to compile this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
/* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

/* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
/* Check for errors */ 
if(res != CURLE_OK)
fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
curl_easy_strerror(res));

/* always cleanup */ 
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Eric/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-    Windows/welcome_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory     '/cygdrive/c/Users/Eric/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/welcome_1 build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-    Windows/welcome.o -lcygcurl-4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygcurl-4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-    Windows/welcome_1.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/welcome_1.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory     '/cygdrive/c/Users/Eric/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory     '/cygdrive/c/Users/Eric/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Welcome_1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 667ms)
```

Comment: Does `libcygcurl-4.so` actually exist? If so, try adding path the library using option -L of the linker.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by manually including the library on the Properties tab of the project

Answer (score 0):

Answer just to close this ask.

For resumate : You success to avoid errors by including Curl library in «Properties» Tab.